# JavaScript - jQuery toggle option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script to execute some tasks based on an option variable. Option has a default value 1. The value can be toggled by clicking some links. Then a set of operations are set, for that operations to execute. The sample layout will be like;

HTML

```
<a id="opt1">1</a><br><a id="opt2">2</a><br><a id="opt3">3</a><br>
<div id="mydiv">option1</div>
```

JS

```
var opt=1;
$('#opt1').click(function() {
    opt=1;
});
$('#opt2').click(function() {
    opt=2;
});
$('#opt3').click(function() {
    opt=3;
});
if(opt == 1){
    $('#mydiv').text("option1");
}else if(opt == 2){
    $('#mydiv').text("option2");
}else{
    $('#mydiv').text("option3");
}
```

JS is wrapped inside document ready function. The sample is meant to change text according to option variable. Sorry that the tasks cannot be nested inside `.click(function()` and are purely depend on option value. How can I achieve this?

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Naw3y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is your `if` condition is called just once on document.ready.. make a function , add your condition and call that function in click event

```
var opt=1;
$('#opt1').click(function() {
  opt=1;
  divText(opt); //calling divText(1) is shorter :)
});
$('#opt2').click(function() {
  opt=2;
  divText(opt)
});
$('#opt3').click(function() {
  opt=3;
  divText(opt)
});

function divText(opt){
 if(opt == 1){
  $('#mydiv').text("option1");
 }else if(opt == 2){
  $('#mydiv').text("option2");
}else{
  $('#mydiv').text("option3");
 }
}
```

not sure why aren't you calling straight away .. without if and function.. but here you go

```
$('#opt1').click(function() {
  $('#mydiv').text("option1");
});
$('#opt2').click(function() {
  $('#mydiv').text("option2");
});
$('#opt3').click(function() {
  $('#mydiv').text("option3");
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Naw3y/2/)
[fiddle for second option](http://jsfiddle.net/Naw3y/5/)

Comment: I already know the direct way, but due to some needs, i need the first one. Thanks.. :)

Comment: hehe.. :).. welcome... i was just wondering why not that and mentioned it.. anyways.... glad it helped... happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/Naw3y/6/:

```
var opt = 1;

$(function() {

$('#opt1').click(function() {
    opt=1;
    changeText();
});

$('#opt2').click(function() {
    opt=2;
    changeText();
});

$('#opt3').click(function() {
    opt=3;
    changeText();
});

});

function changeText(){
 if(opt == 1){
  $('#mydiv').text("option1");
 }else if(opt == 2){
  $('#mydiv').text("option2");
}else{
  $('#mydiv').text("option3");
 }
}
```

Comment: I already mentioned that that the tasks cannot be nested inside `.click(function()` and are purely depend on option value

Comment: @blasteralfred: Fixed my answer according to your needs by using a help function and a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need in your situation is 'encapsulation' of your property, and this is what the other answers lack:

```
var opt;
//setter function for opt that does the div update
function setOpt(value) {
    opt = value;
    $('#mydiv').text('option' + value);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    //bind click handlers
    $('#opt1').click(function() {
        setOpt(1);
    });
    $('#opt2').click(function() {
        setOpt(2);
    });
    $('#opt3').click(function() {
        setOpt(3);
    });
    //set default value
    setOpt(1);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
       $('#mydiv').text('option'+$(this).html());
   });
});
```

Sorry If i didnt understand your question well.. try to explain better..

Comment: As @blasteralfred said: "The sample is meant to change text according to option variable. Sorry that the tasks cannot be nested inside .click(function() and are purely depend on option value."